# Is it okay to put code in the app/ folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, directory-structure

I have a set of Rails applications that are based on the same template. I'm trying to make it so there is a singleton configured for every application. My feeling is that the code representing the base of the singleton would go into the `/lib` folder, as this code repeats across applications, and to put specific code inside the `/app` folder.

Does putting my module directly into the `/app` directory make sense?

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? I don't really understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: Have you tried looking at [Rails Engines](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html)?